# Bootstrap's pull-right class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<th>Cars <i class="fa fa-sort-asc pull-right"></i></th>
```

When I am using bootstrap's `pull-right` class, it aligns the icon in my `th` to the top right corner, and removing `pull-right` aligns the icon centered vertically to the left, but is there a way so that when I use `pull-right` it's aligned in the center vertically to the right?

I am using **bootstrap** and icons from **fontawesome**

Comment: Show rest of your code that vertically aligns your `TH`

Comment: why do you want absolutely to use the `pull-right`if without it you get the rendering you want ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap, and I am meaning the <i> element inside the th if that was misunderstood, the <i> is automatically aligned in the center vertically when I am not using the pull-right class. But using pull-right puts it in the top right corner

Comment: I want to use pull-right so the icon is on the right side of the th

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pull-left` on the span instead..

```
<th class="text-right">
     <span class="pull-left">First Name</span>
     <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
</th>
```

http://codeply.com/go/DIWtVsyMwh

In **Bootstrap 4**, `pull-left` is now `float-left`, and `pull-right` is now `float-right`

Comment: Score for the bootstrap 4 changes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the icon on the right and vertically aligned with the text like this:

**HTML**

```
<th>
  <div class="header-with-icon">
    <div>First Name</div>
    <div class="text-right"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i></div>
  </div>
</th>
```

**CSS**

```
.header-with-icon{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-with-icon > div{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's a bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/Df5JpMyU2k